# QFileDialog as editor for TableView closes when losing focus

Tags: python, qt, delegates, editor, tableview

I have a `QTableView` with associated `QAbstractTableModel` that contains directory names in some columns. I would like to use a `QFileDialog` as the editor to change those columns. This a little unusual, as the editor is not going to be inside the table cell (not enough space).

I got the basics working using a `QStyledItemDelegate`:

```
class DirectorySelectionDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):        
        editor = QFileDialog(parent)
        editor.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)       
        editor.resize(400, 400)
        return editor   

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        val = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        fs = val.rsplit(os.path.sep, 1)
        if len(fs) == 2:
            bdir, vdir = fs
        else:
            bdir = "."
            vdir = fs[0]

        editor.setDirectory(bdir)        
        editor.selectFile(vdir)                    

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.selectedFiles())
```

When double-clicking the cell it starts a `QFileDialog`, I can select the directory I want and on Choose it is set in the model.

However, if for whatever reason the `QFileDialog` loses focus it is closed, and the data is set to the original value. I would prefer the dialog to be open until the user clicks Cancel or Choose, but I cannot find a way to do that.

**Bonus question:** for some reason the dialog ignores the `resize()` call and starts up very small (which makes losing the focus all the more likely). How can I change the size of the dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

The standard views are not containers of widgets, each cell is drawn when necessary. The widget used for editing is only created and superimposed on top of the view whenever an editing trigger is generated. The delegate is then called to create the appropriate editing widget and the location and size of the cell are passed in as an argument.

The view retains ownership of the editor widget because, whenever focus is lost, you can obviously not be able to edit anymore so the view deletes the editor.

If you do not pass anything back in the `setModelData` function, the model will not be updated. It is not correct to say that the model is set back to the original data because it never gets changed in the first place.

What I would suggest you try is setting the `QFileDialog` to open modally (`editor.setModal(true)`) so that the dialog has to be closed before focus can be transferred to another widget.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried that, and it helps a little in that it does not give the focus back to my application, but if another application gets focus the editor is still closed. But it sounds like that's what it's supposed to do, so I'll have to live with it.

Comment: Concerning `setModelData`: how can I tell whether the dialog was closed with Choose or Cancel? `setModelData` is called with the same values in both cases. Confused...

Comment: By checking what you get from `QDialog::result()`

Comment: Hm, I don't see that in the PyQT documentation for [QFileDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html), and if I print `editor.result()` in `setModelData` I always get `0`. I opened  a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868856/qfiledialog-as-editor-for-tableview-how-to-get-result) for this. Thanks!