# QFileDialog as editor for TableView: how to get result?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qfiledialog

I'm using a `QFileDialog` as the editor for some columns in a `QTableView`. This basically works (modulo some focus issues, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854242/qfiledialog-as-editor-for-tableview-closes-when-losing-focus)):

```
class DirectorySelectionDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QFileDialog(parent)
        editor.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)       
        editor.setModal(True)
        return editor    

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        val = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        fs = val.rsplit(os.path.sep, 1)
        if len(fs) == 2:
            bdir, vdir = fs
        else:
            bdir = "."
            vdir = fs[0]

        editor.setDirectory(bdir)        
        editor.selectFile(vdir)        

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.selectedFiles()[0])   

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        r = option.rect
        r.setHeight(600)
        r.setWidth(600)            
        editor.setGeometry(r)
```

However, when the editor is closed I don't see a way to differentiate between `Choose` and `Cancel` (or lost focus), the `setEditorData` function is called in all cases. I don't see a way to get the result from `QFileDialog` that I get as `editor`, all examples I can find use the return value from `exec_`, which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setModelData`, it looks like you could check the editor's [result](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#result) before setting the model's data. By default, the result is `QDialog.Rejected`, and that should only change if the user actually chooses a file:

```
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.result() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            model.setData(index, editor.selectedFiles()[0])
```

**UPDATE**:

After some belated testing, it's obvious that no matter how the file-dialog is run (even with `exec`), its `result` will never get properly reset in the context of a delegate editor. So a little indirection is needed. According to the docs for [QFileDialog.filesSelected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#filesSelected), this signal will always and only be sent when the dialog is accepted (even if there are no selected files). So we can use this mechanism to force the correct dialog result, like this:

```
class DirectorySelectionDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtGui.QFileDialog(parent)
        editor.filesSelected.connect(
            lambda: editor.setResult(QtGui.QDialog.Accepted))
        ...

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        print(editor.result())
        if editor.result() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            model.setData(index, editor.selectedFiles()[0])
```

Comment: Interestingly I always get `0` (`Rejected`), no matter whether I click `Choose`, `Cancel` or close the dialog through losing focus or just plain closing it. Something is wrong here...

Comment: @DirkR. Serves me right for not testing. See my updated answer for a proper solution.

Comment: Ingenious and elegant. Thank you very much for your solution!