# QFileDialog in QTableView: is it posssible to change between directory and file?

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, delegates, qfiledialog

I want to to something similar to that:
[QFileDialog as editor for TableView: how to get result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868856/qfiledialog-as-editor-for-tableview-how-to-get-result)

I want to modify the code so that someone can use the delegate for files and for directories.

Some kind of

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, option_dir, index):
        editor = QFileDialog(parent)
        editor.setFileMode(option_dir)
```

Is that possible to do it with a parameter or do i have to subclass the delegate?

Where would i have to pass the parameter to the delegate?

Comment: your question is unclear, what is `option_dir?`

Comment: `option_dir` is the paramatername whether it is for directories or files. For example `option_dir = QFileDialog.ExistingFile` or `option_dir = QFileDialog.Directory`

Comment: @mikesmitti You can't pass extra arguments to `createEditor` because it's called internally by qt. But in any case, how is the user going to select which option they want? Where would `option_dir` come from?

Comment: A good question indeed. But needing two different classes when only one additional parameter for one method is diffferent, is not what I expected from Python.